# Why can javac not find a symbol in the same class?

Tags: java, generics

The class is generic  , let's say  `Generic<T>` and contains this:

```
private int count;
public int Count()
{
  return count;
}
```

It has a method that raises compiler error.  It cannot find symbol `Count()` (or `count`) of class `Generic<capture#940 of ? extends T>` and points to these lines:

```
public void set(Generic<? extends T> other)
{
  int something = other.Count();
  int somethingElse = other.count;
  //actions
}
```

Why is the symbol not found in `other` ?  I put it there.
Also, any tips on how to tag this question.  I cannot figure out how to distinguish it from questions of package scope, class calls, subclassing, delegation, namespaces, or the like.  And no one has used 'cannot-find-symbol'.

Comment: You have to go through the public accessor method to get to the private field. Why is your class generic?

Comment: I don't need to access the private field.  Currently I'm compiling with just the call to count().  The class is generic because it models a generic object.  It contains more than what I have put here.  But I should be able to access the private field too, as you will note with any nongeneric class.

Comment: My previous comment might miscommunicate I am successfully compiling. I mean I am trying and getting the compiler error.  Why cannot I find the method count()?  Is other not  the same type  as this class?

Comment: oh, and your methods should not start with a capital letter, and the method should be named getCount(), other comments about following the java coding conventions. :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extended comment, rather than an answer.

The following program compiles without errors in Eclipse:

```
public class Generic<T> {
  private int count;
  public int Count()
  {
    return count;
  }
  public void set(Generic<? extends T> other)
  {
    int something = other.Count();
    int somethingElse = other.count;
  }
}
```

Please add more information. If my program does not compile in your environment, you should post information about the compile. If my program does compiler, you could post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung
I missed an angle bracket somewhere.  Still confused the compiler would point to where it did and not where the parser actually lost track.  Thank you Patricia, Zagrev.

I'd like to show an example of successfully referring to other.count, the field, but my maximum characters are too small for that.

Comment: The compiler goes on parsing as long as the code it has processed so far is a prefix of at least one syntactically-correct program, even if that program has nothing to do with what you meant. Missing punctuation tends to cause a mismatch between the programmer's intent and the compiler's view. If an error makes no sense, look **backwards** from the indicated location for a mistake. Viewing, and reformatting, the code in an IDE with syntax highlight may also bring out the actual problem.